# How to secure JSON requests from iPhone?

Tags: ios, json, ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I have a web app with a JSONP API I'm using with my iPhone app. How do I secure this so requests from other places won't be able to access my API?

**Clarification**: My data isn't that important. You don't even have to sign in to view it. I just don't want by my database to work on queries from other sources.

Comment: After your clarification, I suggest the answer that I gave. That's what I use in about 4 production apps.  To reiterate, make sure your web service endpoints start with https and just put in a secret string into each request (either in the header or the actual body). Does that make sense?  In iPhone, I use ASIHTTPRequest and add the header like so: [request addRequestHeader:@"Secret-Header" value:@"WJQPSWDWEPONSDMNVOEOIWUER"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have embarked on a very very complicated subject. Prepare yourself for some very long nights of reading various cat and mouse techniques of securing your app.  I think your best bet is to put a secret string in the header of each request.  Something like this:

Secret-Header: #$F@FQAFDSFE#$%#ADSF())*

Validate that header on the server side and use SSL.  Someone could easily respond to this post with "Well that doesn't stop this, this and this" and they will be right.  The question is, are you a bank that is worried about someone draining your client's accounts?  Or are you just worried about 99.9999% of the population not being willed enough to hijack your junk?

Some people have all kinds of opinions on this, but if your users require authentication to access the web services, just require the username and password to be sent in the header via SSL.  They can still hijack your services, but wouldn't be able to see anything that they weren't supposed to anyway.  That only works on a user level type of setup though. If it's completely public, you have to consider how unimportant your data is. It may not be as important as you think.

Comment: how do you set the Secret-Header value in the first place? My understanding is that you don't want to ship secret value built into in an iOS application.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a private RSA key in the iPhone client and send a signed timestamp with each request.
The server would verify the timestamp against the public key and reject unsigned requests.

The enemy can disassemble the iPhone client and steal the key, and you can't do a thing about it.
(other than a blacklisting arms race)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TLS protocol with client certificate.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

The only problem with this solution (not solved today) is that the client certificate is stored in the app binary and can be retro-eenginered.

Comment: For TLS client certificate implementation on iPhone use ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use AFNetworking don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

One traditional way to do this is to take all of the url variables you are requesting, add a 'secret' string, and hash the whole thing and add it as an additional url variable. On your API side, you do the same thing, and if the hash matches what you were given, it's probably coming from your app.